# if $U$ is a $T$ - invariant subspace and $T$ is isomorphism, then $T|_U$ is isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

As part of another proof, I'm trying to prove that if $V$ is a vector space and $U$ is a subspace of $V$, and $T$ is isomorphism, and $U$ is $T$ - invariant, then $T|_U$ is also isomorphism, given that $\dim V < \infty$. It seems obvious but I'm having trouble formalizing, like something is missing. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In finite dimensional vector spaces, saying that $T:V \to V$ is an isomorphism is the same as saying that there is a map $T^{-1}$ such that $T^{-1}T = I$.  That is, for every $x \in V$, we have $T^{-1}(T(x)) = x$.

Now, I claim that $T^{-1}|_U$ is the inverse map of $T$.  How can we see this? What we need to show is that every $x \in U$, $T^{-1}|_U (T|_U(x)) = x$.  But this is obvious: after all, $T|_U(x)$ is just $T(x)$, and $T^{-1}|_U(y)$ is just $T(y)$.  All together,
$$
T^{-1}|_U (T|_U(x)) = T^{-1}|_U (T(x)) = T^{-1} (T(x)) = x
$$

Comment: There's nothing all that special in the infinite dimensional case.  To make this proof work, however, we should separately require that $T(T^{-1}(x)) = x$.

Comment: I derped before. This is perfectly correct. I didn't see the iso stipulation!

Comment: I don't think this is sufficient as a proof, because for $T^{-1}|_U$ to be the inverse map, also $T|_U(T^{-1}|_U(x)) = x$ must hold. However, $T^{-1}|_U(x)$ is not necessairly in U, an therefore $T|_U$ is not surjective (and not defined on $T^{-1}|_U(x)$). So I think the argument should go like $T$ is injective $\implies T|_U$ is injektive, and because for Endomorphisms injektive is equivalent to surjektive to bijektive, it is an Isomorphism.